# transact with laravel elequent

Tags: php, laravel

i have laravel project
now i have item table which connect with multi ather table 
like item_state item_colors item_barcode ect 
now in the page of adding items its ok 
in store function i have this code

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $item = new Item;
    $item->item_id = $request['item_id'];
    $item->item_desc_ar = $request['item_desc_ar'];
    $item->item_desc_en = $request['item_desc_en'];
    $item->item_default_unit = $request['item_default_unit'];
    $item->item_color = $request['item_color'];
    $item->item_width = $request['item_width'];
    $item->item_length = $request['item_length'];
    $item->item_height = $request['item_height'];
    $item->item_inserter = Auth::user()->id;
    $item->item_state = $request['item_state'];
    $item->item_note = $request['item_note'];
    $item->save();
    $item_barcode = new Item_barcode;
    $item_barcode->item_barcode_item_id = $item->id;
    $item_barcode->item_barcode_barcode = $request->item_barcode;
    $item_barcode->item_barcode_unit = $request->item_default_unit;
    $item_barcode->save();
    foreach($request->category_id as $item_categorys)
    {
        $item_category = new item_category;
        $item_category->category_id = $item_categorys;
        $item_category->item_id = $item->id;
        $item_category->save();
    }
    $item_price = new Item_price;
    $item_price->item_price_item_id = $item->id;
    $item_price->item_price_price = $request->item_price;
    $item_price->item_price_unit_id = $request->item_default_unit;
    $item_price->save();
    $count = 1;
    foreach($request->image as $image)
    {
        if(!empty($image))
        {
            $image_id = $item['id'];
            if(!file_exists(public_path()."/uploads/items/$image_id"))
                File::makeDirectory(base_path()."/public/uploads/items/$image_id");     
            $file = $image;
            $file->move('uploads/items/'.$image_id,$count.'.jpg');
        }
        $count++;
    }
}
```

now i want to do transact thats if the item not added or any wrong in the code nothing happen in the ather table 
like the transact in laravel 
but its not working with elequent model 
thanks .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would be talking about Database Transactions in this case:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/database#database-transactions

You need to wrap your query in the transaction closure:

```
DB::transaction(function () {
    DB::table('users')->update(['votes' => 1]);

    DB::table('posts')->delete();
}, 5);
```

Or manually begin the transaction:

```
DB::beginTransaction();
```

If it fails then:

```
DB::rollBack();
```

and finally:

```
DB::commit();
```

on success.

Here is a good article detailing transactions.

http://fideloper.com/laravel-database-transactions

```
DB::beginTransaction();

try {
    $item = new Item;
    $item->item_id = $request['item_id'];
    $item->item_desc_ar = $request['item_desc_ar'];
    $item->item_desc_en = $request['item_desc_en'];
    $item->item_default_unit = $request['item_default_unit'];
    $item->item_color = $request['item_color'];
    $item->item_width = $request['item_width'];
    $item->item_length = $request['item_length'];
    $item->item_height = $request['item_height'];
    $item->item_inserter = Auth::user()->id;
    $item->item_state = $request['item_state'];
    $item->item_note = $request['item_note'];
    $item->save();
    $item_barcode = new Item_barcode;
    $item_barcode->item_barcode_item_id = $item->id;
    $item_barcode->item_barcode_barcode = $request->item_barcode;
    $item_barcode->item_barcode_unit = $request->item_default_unit;
    $item_barcode->save();
    foreach($request->category_id as $item_categorys)
    {
        $item_category = new item_category;
        $item_category->category_id = $item_categorys;
        $item_category->item_id = $item->id;
        $item_category->save();
    }
    $item_price = new Item_price;
    $item_price->item_price_item_id = $item->id;
    $item_price->item_price_price = $request->item_price;
    $item_price->item_price_unit_id = $request->item_default_unit;
    $item_price->save();
    $count = 1;
    foreach($request->image as $image)
    {
        if(!empty($image))
        {
            $image_id = $item['id'];
            if(!file_exists(public_path()."/uploads/items/$image_id"))
                File::makeDirectory(base_path()."/public/uploads/items/$image_id");     
            $file = $image;
            $file->move('uploads/items/'.$image_id,$count.'.jpg');
        }
        $count++;
    }
    DB::commit();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    DB::rollBack();
}
```

Comment: Doesn't matter, the transactions will work in either case.

Comment: Happy to help. Ta.

Answer (score 1):

```
DB::beginTransaction();
try{
   //Code which can  throw error
   DB::commit();
}catch(Exception $e){
   DB::rollBack();
}
```